# Pywinauto - sometimes actions are not performed on a specific element/window

Tags: pywinauto

Sometimes when I want to click or perform any other actions on a element from a visible window/menu, it does not find the element, even if it's visible and it doesn't perform the required actions.

Stopping/Starting the application fixes the issue temporary but it's a little bit time consuming.

Do you know it there are any other workarounds or solutions in case scenarios like this would occur?

Answer (score 0):

You may try `timings.WaitUntilPasses()` function to repeat some actions until timeout is over or action is done.

If the control is not found next time, it may have different root causes. One of them is that controls layout has been changed (maybe a little) and `best_match` algorithm assigns other names for the controls. Every time it depends on the situation. Please ask more detailed questions about concrete use cases.

There are few more ways to set more precise criterion for the control search. Something like that may help to avoid duplications:

```
# #32770 means a dialog like message box
app.Window_(title='Exact title', class_name='#32770').OK.Click()

# click first button with a "Set" caption (if there are few such buttons)
app.MainWindow.ChildWindow(title='Set', class_name='Button', found_index=0).Click()
```

Full list of possible criteria for search can be found in [find_windows() function docs](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html?highlight=find_windows).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such situation. In my case, the application was too busy to respond to UI actions. So for those specific points, I used a while loop and inside the loop I perform the action and wait for a specific window/control state. If that does not happen then code repeats in the loop. Loop breaks when the action and the expected behaviour is achieved.